# Trying to save HABTM model data in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-2.0, addition, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a data model that requires the use of HABTM, as follows:

```
surveys 
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    title varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY user_id (user_id)
);

questions 
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    body text NOT NULL,
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY user_id (user_id)
);

questions_surveys  
(  
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    survey_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
    question_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
    modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
    PRIMARY KEY (id),  
    KEY survey_id (survey_id),  
    KEY question_id (question_id)  
);
```

And the relevant foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE questions_surveys
ADD CONSTRAINT questions_surveys_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY(survey_id) REFERENCES surveys(id);

ALTER TABLE questions_surveys
ADD CONSTRAINT questions_surveys_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY(question_id) REFERENCES questions(id);
```

Questions and Surveys have an HABTM relationship, so that one survey has many questions and one question can be in many different surveys.

In Survey.php:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'className' => 'Question',
        'joinTable' => 'questions_surveys',
        'foreignKey' => 'survey_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'question_id'
    )
);
```

In Question.php:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Survey' => array(
        'className' => 'Survey',
        'joinTable' => 'questions_surveys',
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'survey_id'
    )
);
```

Here's my add controller from SurveysController.php:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->set('fields', $this->Survey->getFields());
    $this->set('users', $this->Survey->User->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'username'))));
    $this->set('questions', $this->Question->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'body'))));

    if (!empty($this->data))
    {
        $this->Survey->saveAll($this->data['Survey']);

        foreach($this->data['Question']['id'] as $question_id)
        {
            $newdata[] = array('Survey' => array('id' => $this->Survey->getInsertID()), 'Question' => array('id' => $question_id));
        }

        if ($this->Survey->saveAll($newdata))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The survey was successfully added!');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add survey.');
        }
    }
}
```

The new survey is saved first, and then every question_survey is added to an array that then adds all of them at once. The data looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Survey] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                )

            [Question] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'QuestionsSurvey.survey_id' in 'where clause'
>      SQL Query: SELECT `AppModel`.`question_id` FROM `engage`.`questions_surveys` AS `AppModel` WHERE `QuestionsSurvey`.`survey_id` = 13

As far as I can tell, everything is named in accordance with CakePHP standards, and I tried using 'with' => 'QuestionsSurvey', but get this error:

> Missing Database Table
>   Error: Table app_models for model QuestionsSurvey was not found in datasource default.

And 'with' => 'QuestionsSurveys', but get the same error:

> Missing Database Table
>   Error: Table app_models for model QuestionsSurveys was not found in datasource default.

I've tried converting the model trio to a hasMany through model (didn't work, it all just said go back to HABTM).

I've used all kinds of different formats for the data [(CakePHP Saving Your Data)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) but no luck there either.

I'm stumped. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Also, I apologize for the very long entry and code sections but I wanted to make sure to be thorough.

Thank you for your time!
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the book is wrong or I'm misunderstanding it or something, this is the format that worked:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 33
        [question_id] => 9
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 33
        [question_id] => 10
    )
)
```

And this is how it needs to be saved in the controller:

```
if ($this->Survey->QuestionsSurvey->saveAll($newdata))
```

Comment: Nothing else worked! Could you show me the correct format? This has been kicking me in the rear end because I've been trying to start using hasMany through models...

Comment: Look at the answer below!

Answer (score 4):

Your data should look like the following:

```
array(
    'Survey' => array(
        'title' => 'example',
    ),
    'Question' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
    )
)
```

to save the data use:
    `$this->Survey->saveAll($data);`

Thanks